# Petersen's proof of Gauss Lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I don't quite understand a step in Petersen's proof of Gauss Lemma (lemma 5.5.5 [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=YwbNCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=it&pg=PA190#v=onepage&q=gauss%20lemma&f=false)).
After introducing exponential normal coordinates, he defines a vector field $\partial_r$ on $U=\exp_p(B_\varepsilon)$ in coordinates by $\partial_r\vert_{\exp_px}=\frac{1}{r}x^i\partial_i\vert_{\exp_px}$. He then claims that the integral curves of this vector field are unit-speed geodesics and I don't understand why this is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That vector field is a normalized radial vector field (it is $\frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert}$). By construction of the exponential map, its integral curves are the unit-speed geodesics.